# Access ViewController in iOS-Native Extension for Adobe Air

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, air

Short: 
The Android-API for Air-Native-Extensions provides a getActivity() on the Context-Object. 
I am looking for a way, to get the current ViewController in iOS-Native-Extensions

Long:
We need to extend Air with more than just some iOS-API-Calls to access vibration etc, but want to display a View (MPMediaPickerController to select a File from the iTunes library). In the Keynote to native extensions on Adobe MAX 2011 (http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2011-develop/how-to-extend-your-mobile-air-applications-using-native-extensions/) Oliver Goldman said, it is okay to show complete Views by using native extensions.
To show the MPMediaPickerController (or any other View), I need to call presentModalViewController on the current ViewController or need access to the Navigation Controller.
I hoped there is a way to get a pointer to the controller somehow, but I have not found any documentaion about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this piece of code. It works.

```
UIViewController * myViewController;
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIWindow * win = [delegate window];
myViewController = [[MyView alloc] init];
// CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);
// init the view position some how  myViewController.viewFrame = rect;

[win addSubview:myViewController.view];
```

Hope this helps.

Best,
Emil

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I had a UIWebView and wanted to display it, so adding it as a subview of UIView worked. The UIWebView has to be initialized with the specified rect, though

Comment: @Heitara Is it possible to override methods in the UIViewController? Especially: preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures

Comment: @Oldes yes - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887512-preferredscreenedgesdeferringsys