# Show native view and control on an IOS ANE

Tags: ios, objective-c, actionscript-3, air, ane

I'm on my first endeavor of creating an ANE. The final result should be an iOS GoogleMaps ANE.

However, i'm not able to find enough documentation on how to show native controls or views, on top of the Air Stage.

I found the following post, but it only shows some code and i'm not sure if UIApplication is defined, since the xcode project is a static library project.

[Access ViewController in iOS-Native Extension for Adobe Air](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914378/access-viewcontroller-in-ios-native-extension-for-adobe-air)

Can anyone give me some help.

Best reagrds,
Carlos.

Comment: This is kind-of close to what your need, but it is using a bitmap copy to display on the Stage @ https://code.google.com/p/air-maps-ane/

Comment: Thank you @RobertN, but a bitmap copy is not an option. I need full interactivity with the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With FPNativeUI.ane library, you can use any built-in iOS native UI components  programmatically or through XIB. Demonstration here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SP-e_phr7i0 . Download here: http://flashpress.ru/blog/ane/native-ui/?lang=en .