# Twilio Video SDK as an Adobe AIR Native Extension (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ane

I have been busy trying to create a AIR Native Extension to encapsulate the Twilio Video SDK. My colleague succeeded in building it for Android and I have been trying the same for iOS.

I'm in a state where the Extension compiles and the extension runs inside my AIR app, but for some reason, it only displays the local Camera feed and accept incoming calls **IF** I have an active alert opened (UIAlertController).

Apparently, where I trigger such alert is irrelevant, as long as it is open. As soon as I close the alert, the camera feed stops updating, and I can no longer receive incoming Calls.

The strategy to create the ANE is similar to the Android version. We started with the provided sample app, and modified the initialization of the ViewController. The screen components are created on the "viewDidLoad", and after that we call the "retrieveAccessTokenFromURL" method of the SDK.

Is it possible that iOS is forcing the screen to go to a "sleep mode" if such thing exist? Or blocking some capabilities?

Out of the similar questions, I can see we are following this approach:
[Access ViewController in iOS-Native Extension for Adobe Air](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914378/access-viewcontroller-in-ios-native-extension-for-adobe-air)

Any help is aprpeciated.

Comment: I would really appreciate if Downvoters could at least explain why. I have spent a day trying to figure out what seems to be a strange behaviour that I cannot really explain.
There are no errors being logged, the ViewController does not call its "viewWillUnload" (deprecated) or "viewWillDisappear". I have researched to the best of my abilities, but seems the issue is too specific.

Comment: I have been trying to build same feature for iOS. Currently, Twilio sdk is not recognising my camera's. They are returning nil when listing camera. Can you please help me with sample code? Or please point out your development twilio and air versions?